# How can I analyze a virtual market for arbitrage where volume data is not available?

Tags: data-visualization, data-mining, econometrics, algorithms, trend

I've been tracking various virtual worlds (World of Warcraft, Diablo 3, etc.) and their associated virtual markets. Interestingly, there usually is a potential for arbitrage based on a number of factors (European players vs North American, Day vs Night, Weekday vs Weekend, etc). The type and amount of data available can vary greatly, however, and therefore makes tracking and analysis somewhat difficult.

My current project revolves around a virtual economy that has an auction house type marketplace where players can post goods for auction. However, no data is available regarding volume of auctions. At best, I have been able to record auction postings and the amount of the goods being listed. For example, a stack of potatoes might be listed for 10 units of currency as a starting bid and 15 units to buy out the entire lot. The listing shows number of potatoes (i.e. 100).

My main problem is that I can't track whether items are purchased versus if they simply expire or are pulled by the poster. Obviously I can come up with the total amount of items listed at any given time, but what useful knowledge can I gain from this data?

More specifically, I'd like to know more about the following:

1. What type of analysis would be most useful to determine whether price fluctuations (if any) are subject to exploitation?
2. What is the best way to visually represent the data considering both price and amount of goods listed on the auction house?
3. Are there any specific Python or R packages which would be useful for visualizing and analyzing this data set?